# numerical partial derivative in MatLab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

How can I compute the numerical partial derivative of a probability density function (PDF) in Matlab? I'm not looking for a solution using automatic differences or a symbolic solution.

Given the following example:

```
arg = (-1:.01:1)';
mu = 0;
sigma = 0.5;

f = normpdf(arg,mu,sigma);
```

Is it possible to compute the numerical partial derivative of `df/dsigma`? Or am I stuck to having to use the automatic differences or the Symbolic Math toolbox?

Comment: Are you looking for the partial derivative with respect to sigma, given arg and mu, right?

Comment: @randomatlabuser correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the actual function is not the PDF of the normal distribution. You might try using [complex step differentiation](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/) if you only need the first derivative:

```
mu = 0;
sigma = 0.5;
f = @(x)normpdf(x,mu,sigma);
x = -1:0.01:1;
h = 2^-28;
dx = imag(f(x+1i*h))/h;
```

Or if you hold `x` and `mu` constant and vary `sigma`:

```
mu = 0;
x = 0;
g = @(sigma)normpdf(x,mu,sigma);
sigma = 0.25:0.01:0.75;
h = 2^-28;
dsigma = imag(g(sigma+1i*h))/h;
```

This technique is fast, simple, and very accurate. You can download this as a convenient function, [`cdiff`](https://github.com/horchler/cdiff), from my GitHub.

Comment: won't this give me the derivative and not the partial derivative?

Comment: No, in each case the derivative is only with respect to a single variable – all others are held constant. You can check this by comparing it with the output from symbolic partial differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that arg and mu are constant and sigma varies. This is an obvious approximation:

```
arg = 0;
mu = 0;
incr = 0.0001;
sigma = incr:incr:1.5;

f = normpdf(arg,mu,sigma);
d = diff(f) / incr;
plot(sigma(2:end), d, '.')
set(gca, 'XLim', [0.05 1.5])
```