# Differentiate function without Symbolic Math Toolbox

Tags: matlab, diff, symbolic-math

If I want to differentiate a function, I would do the following:

```
syms x
f(x) = sin(x^2);
df = diff(f)
```

,but that requires the use of the Symbolic Math Toolbox (for the `syms` function).
Is there a workaround (an alternative) to this method without the use of the Symbolic Toolbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [numerical partial derivative in MatLab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257508/numerical-partial-derivative-in-matlab) as well as [Calculate the derivative of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613859/calculate-the-derivative-of-a-vector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a **numerical vector** and you'd like to differentiate it, then the [**`gradient`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) function is your friend.

If you want to differentiate a **symbolic expressing** then the **Symbolic Math Toolbox** is the only way to go within Matlab. If pen&paper together with [**wolframalpha.com**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) does not serve you, there is no way around to buy the toolbox or use alternatives like Wolframs Mathematica, Maple, Maxima, Sympy, Sage etc..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assumed that this is the case, but I decided to ask the comunity:)

Comment: @ViharChervenkov see also [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net), [Sympy](http://sympy.org), [Sage](http://sagemath.org), etc.

Comment: @RobertDodier I should have mentioned some other free alternatives, that's right ;) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59438-symbolic-derivatives

In the above link, you will find a function that requires string 'sin(x^2)' as input and gives you something like 'cos(x^2)*2*x' (i.e. also a string). You may then use standard Matlab's eval() to evaluate the derivative numerically at any x point.