# plot a function depending on its differential coefficient

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

Say I have an differential coefficient such as

> partial(Q)/partial(g)=f(Q,g).

And I have an initial value of {Q,g} as {10,10}.

How can I get the value of {Q,g} around {10,10} and plot a figure of {Q,g}?

Comment: Your question is a bit too abstract. Provide a concrete example of what you mean. And don't use code/text to represent equations (upload an image of a TeX/LaTeX equation if you really need that). If you just want to take the (partial) derivative of a function at a point, see this [Calculate the derivative of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20613859/2278029) or [numerical partial derivative in MatLab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20257508/2278029).