# Solve a non-linear system of equations with differentiation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, non-linear

I would like to solve a system of non-linear equations in Matlab with `fsolve`, but I also have to differentiate the functions with respect to two variables. Here is the problem in steps:

Step 1: I define the system of non-linear functions `F`:

```
function F = root2d(x)
 
F(1) = (exp(-x(1)+2)/(1+exp(-x(1)+2)+exp(-x(2)+1)));
F(2) = (exp(-x(2)+1)/(1+exp(-x(1)+2)+exp(-x(2)+1)));

end
```

Step 2: I want to find the derivative of `F(1)` with respect to `x(1)` and the derivative of `F(2)` with respect to `x(2)` such that:

```
function F = root2d(x)
 
F(1) = (exp(-x(1)+2)/(1+exp(-x(1)+2)+exp(-x(2)+1)));
F(2) = (exp(-x(2)+1)/(1+exp(-x(1)+2)+exp(-x(2)+1)));

f1_d=diff(F(1),x(1))
f1_d=diff(F(2),x(2))

end
```

Step 3: I want my function to be the original one plus the derivative:

```
function F = root2d(x)
 
F(1) = (exp(-x(1)+2)/(1+exp(-x(1)+2)+exp(-x(2)+1)));
F(2) = (exp(-x(2)+1)/(1+exp(-x(1)+2)+exp(-x(2)+1)));

f1_d=diff(F(1),x(1));
f1_d=diff(F(2),x(2));

F(1)=F(1)+f1_d;
F(2)=F(2)+f2_d;

end
```

Step 4: In the main file I would use this function with `fsolve` to solve the system of non-linear equations for `x(1)` and `x(2)`:

```
syms x
fun = @root2d;
x0 = [0,0];
x = fsolve(fun,x0);
root2d(x)


function F = root2d(x)
 
F(1) = (exp(-x(1)+2)/(1+exp(-x(1)+2)+exp(-x(2)+1)));
F(2) = (exp(-x(2)+1)/(1+exp(-x(1)+2)+exp(-x(2)+1)));

f1_d=diff(F(1),x(1));
f1_d=diff(F(2),x(2));

F(1)=F(1)+f1_d;
F(2)=F(2)+f2_d;
end
```

Can you please help me, how can a rewrite my code in order to solve the derivatives and then calculate and solve the system? Calculation of the derivates by hand is not an option because later I have to develop this program and I will have about 100 equations instead of 2.

Comment: You describe the premise here, but I'm not seeing any problem? Maybe I'm missing something. You seem to describe very clearly the steps you're taking, and then you ask how to do it? Did you try running what you've got? Is there something you suspect is wrong about the answers (what do you think is wrong?) or are you asking how to automate this? I'm having a hard time telling what you're needing help with.

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental problem that you're making is that you're solving this system numerically with `fsolve` but then mixing in symbolic math.

Since your functions, `F` don't seem to vary, their derivatives shouldn't either, so you can create them as symbolic functions and calculate their derivatives symbolically once:

```
syms x [1 2] real; % Create 1-by-2 symbolic vector

F = exp(-x+2)/(1+exp(-x(1)+2)+exp(-x(2)+1));

F_d(1) = diff(F(1),x(1));
F_d(2) = diff(F(2),x(2));

F = F+F_d; % Add derivatives to original functions
```

Then you can convert these to a numerical form and solve with `fsolve`:

```
root2d = matlabFunction(F,'Vars',{x}); % Convert symbolic function to vectorized numeric function
x0 = [0 0];
x = fsolve(root2d,x0)
root2d(x)
```

Note that `fsolve` only finds a single root (if it succeeds) for a given initial guess. It's strongly suggested that you plot your function to understand it's behavior and how many roots it may have. From my limited plotting it doesn't look like this function, as defined above, has any zeros. Separately, you should also look into the tolerance options for `fsolve`.

You can look into purely numerical (non-symbolic) methods to solve this, but you'll need properly calculate the derivative numerically. You might look into [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20257710/2278029) for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution! Still, the problem is that my functions F(1) and F(2) differ, since F(1) has a +2 in the nominator, while F(2) has a +1 in the nominator. So defining F as F=exp(-x+2)/(1+exp(-x(1)+2)+exp(-x(2)+1)); is not possible. Do you have maybe a suggestion for this? Thank you very very much!

Comment: Then you may have a typo in your question. In your question the denominators are identical.

Comment: Regardless, you can still define `F(1)` and `F(2)` however you like in place of my one line.